# Save print data into database

Tags: printing

In Windows I want all the pages printed via a printer in my machine to be saved in to a MYSQL database.I have equipment integrated software, which reads the data from the equipment and displays it. The only way for me to get the data out is by printing. I need to get this printed data directly into my MYSQL  database every time I print.

Comment: OS? DB? Language? Please be as specific as you can when posting questions, otherwise you can't really help.

Comment: OS is windows and need data in MYSQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not very well described, but in general terms I believe that the best bet would be to install a [virtual printer driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_printer) (there are dozens available for Windows, some for free, some for sale).

If you need to save this as an image (because the readings have a graphical part too) you better find something that can produce PDFs or TIFF and design your tables accordingly.
Otherwise you need a driver that mimics a "text only" printer.

You will also need a way to periodically scan the directory where the printouts are stored (a simple polling mechanism should do) in order to identify newly created files and import these in your DB.

This looks mostly as a workflow automation problem, so maybe you could check Superuser.com too, and possibly ask the same question there (but please be more descriptive).

Here is a [description of the standard, text-only virtual printer](http://www.frogmorecs.com/arts/using-the-generic-driver) available in Windows XP.

Here is a product called [PrintMulti](http://www.lvbprint.de/html/printmulti1.html) which seems to provide a good fit.